# How can I create R code to organize my files?

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to create an R project entitled "myproject" accessible directly in your working directory and respecting the architecture next: the "myproject" folder, contains the "project1" folder; this folder "project1", contains the subfolders "data", "program" and "results".
How could I write this R script?. Thanks

Comment: This looks like homework. What did you try?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with

```
sapply(c("data", "program","results"), function(v) dir.create(file.path("myproject","project1",v), recursive = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the code is working very well.

Comment: @KFIADD Great! If you like this solution, then take it accepted such that case closed.